# Match web site page to smartphones

Tags: smartphone

How can i match web site page to smartphones ? 
Just playing with the size and px ? 
There is some routine ?

Thanks in advance , 
Polic.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a website that works good in the panorama and normal mode, we worked here with a fluid design so it uses the whole screen, and it also has some fixed elements inside